# Getting External Headphones (8): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) error when I am trying to use maximilian

Tags: c++, audio, juce

I am testing out using the maximilian library with JUCE. I am trying to use the maxiSample feature and I have implemented it exactly how the example code says to. Whenever I run the standalone app, I get the error "External Headphones (8): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" and it gives me a breakpoint at line 747 of maximilian.cpp. It's not my headphones as it does the same thing with any playback device. Truly at a loss.

I've attached my MainComponent.cpp below. Any advice would be great, thank you!

```
#include "MainComponent.h"
#include "maximilian.h"

//==============================================================================
MainComponent::MainComponent()
{
    // Make sure you set the size of the component after
    // you add any child components.
    setSize (800, 600);

    // Some platforms require permissions to open input channels so request that here
    if (juce::RuntimePermissions::isRequired (juce::RuntimePermissions::recordAudio)
        && ! juce::RuntimePermissions::isGranted (juce::RuntimePermissions::recordAudio))
    {
        juce::RuntimePermissions::request (juce::RuntimePermissions::recordAudio,
                                           [&] (bool granted) { setAudioChannels (granted ? 2 : 0, 2); });
    }
    else
    {
        // Specify the number of input and output channels that we want to open
        setAudioChannels (2, 2);
    }
}

MainComponent::~MainComponent()
{
    // This shuts down the audio device and clears the audio source.
    shutdownAudio();
    sample1.load("/Users/(username)/JuceTestPlugins/maxiSample/Source/kick.wav");
}

//==============================================================================
void MainComponent::prepareToPlay (int samplesPerBlockExpected, double sampleRate)
{
    // This function will be called when the audio device is started, or when
    // its settings (i.e. sample rate, block size, etc) are changed.

    // You can use this function to initialise any resources you might need,
    // but be careful - it will be called on the audio thread, not the GUI thread.

    // For more details, see the help for AudioProcessor::prepareToPlay()
    
}

void MainComponent::getNextAudioBlock (const juce::AudioSourceChannelInfo& bufferToFill)
{
    // Your audio-processing code goes here!

    // For more details, see the help for AudioProcessor::getNextAudioBlock()

    // Right now we are not producing any data, in which case we need to clear the buffer
    // (to prevent the output of random noise)
    //bufferToFill.clearActiveBufferRegion();
    for(int sample = 0; sample < bufferToFill.buffer->getNumSamples(); ++sample){
        
        //float sample2 = sample1.
        //float wave = tesOsc.sinewave(200);
        //double sample2 = sample1.play();
        
//        leftSpeaker[sample] = (0.25 * wave);
//        rightSpeaker[sample] = leftSpeaker[sample];
        double *output;
        output[0] = sample1.play();
        output[1] = output[0];
        
    }
    
    
}

void MainComponent::releaseResources()
{
    // This will be called when the audio device stops, or when it is being
    // restarted due to a setting change.

    // For more details, see the help for AudioProcessor::releaseResources()
}

//==============================================================================
void MainComponent::paint (juce::Graphics& g)
{
    // (Our component is opaque, so we must completely fill the background with a solid colour)
    g.fillAll (getLookAndFeel().findColour (juce::ResizableWindow::backgroundColourId));

    // You can add your drawing code here!
}

void MainComponent::resized()
{
    // This is called when the MainContentComponent is resized.
    // If you add any child components, this is where you should
    // update their positions.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure, but couple of things catch my attention.

In getNextAudioBlock() you are dereferencing invalid pointers:

```
double *output;
output[0] = sample1.play();
output[1] = output[0];
```

The pointer variable `output` is uninitialised and will probably be filled with garbage or zeros, which will make the program read from invalid memory. This problem is most likely to cause the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. This method is called from the realtime audio thread, so you probably get a crash on a non-main thread (in this case the thread of `External Headphones (8)`).

It also is no clear to me what exactly it is you're trying to do here, so it's hard for me to say how it should be. What I can say is that assigning the result of sample1.play() to a double value looks suspicious.

Normally, when dealing with `juce::AudioSourceChannelInfo` you would get pointers to the audio buffers like so:

```
auto** bufferPointer = bufferToFill.buffer->getArrayOfWritePointers()
```

Further, you are loading a file inside the destructor of MainComponent. This at least is suspicious, why would you load a file during destruction?

```
MainComponent::~MainComponent()
{
    // This shuts down the audio device and clears the audio source.
    shutdownAudio();
    sample1.load("/Users/(username)/JuceTestPlugins/maxiSample/Source/kick.wav");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! The error is actually cause by the sample1.load function. I put it in the destructor because I was confused why it was causing the error and tried moving it around because I was starting to get desperate. All I'm trying to do is play an audio sample using maximilian. The invalid pointers came directly from maximilian's example of how to use maxiSample. Still unsure exactly how to solve the issue. I moved the sample1.load to prepareToPlay() but still get the issue.